# Ruby key & Value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby key & value fields to save a jquery function to the database and everything works fine but how can I separate the value params?

```
def update_background
  key = "#{current_user}.profile.background"
  settings = Settings.find_by_key(key) || Settings.new(key: key)
  settings.value = params[:bg_id], params[:color_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      if settings.save
        render text: "success"
      else
        render text: "failure"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above code works fine but the problem is my css is not formatted properly. The code usually shows like so

```
background:  url(../assets/stripes.png rgb(76, 72, 128))
```

In my helper file.

```
def saved_background
  key = "#{current_user}.profile.background"
  settings = Settings.find_by_key(key)
   if settings
     "url(#{settings.value})"
  end
end
```

How can I separate the 2 params in value so that my code will look like

```
background: rgb(76, 72, 128) url(../assets/stripes.png)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically saving an array to `settings.value`, and using it all within the `url` string.

Either separate the settings into individual values, or use each element individually:

```
"url(#{settings.value[0]}) #{settings.value[1]}"
```

---

*Edit* Ah, it's an AR field--so it's likely being saved as just the string rep of the array. Trivial to check, and you should have already.

You need to save it in the format you actually want it--so:

```
settings.value = "url(#{params[:bg_id]}) #{params[:color_id]}"
```

And:

```
def saved_background
  key = "#{current_user}.profile.background"
  settings = Settings.find_by_key(key)
  settings.value if settings
end
```

Comment: does not output value when using the above method but when removing array index number I can see value. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @coletrain Updated; missed it was an AR field.